# Assigned Azure AD Roles missing in User Claims in Blazor Client App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created a role for within an Azure App registration and assigned to me.

This is the role
[image]

This is the assignment in the enterprise application

[image]

Now in the Blazor **Client** App,when i try to read the User roles assigned it is empty

```
var authstate = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authstate.User;
        userName = user.Identity.Name;
        var x = user.Claims.Where(t => t.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();
```

The dependencyInjection is Program.cs looks like this

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("User.Read");


});
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: `Roles are specific to the application. The role claims for one application are not sent to another application.`  Could you pls let me know if the azure ad app you used in your application to make it integrate AAD was the same one which created the role?

Comment: @TinyWang Yes, I created it using the inbuilt tool provided by MS in VS.

Comment: but...as you can see I can get it. could you pls share more code snippet so that we may try to reproduce ?

Comment: @TinyWang Can you share your `Program.cs` where you do the relevant dependency injection

Comment: I test in a mvc web app.and I shared the AAD related code in program.cs

Comment: @TinyWang I'm using Blazor Web Assembly, so the DI is different.

Comment: Did you assign the right permission for `User.Read`?

Comment: @Nb777 How do i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
// Add services to the container.
//builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
// Add the Microsoft Identity UI pages for signin/out
.AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

=====================================================

I can get the roles, as you can see, I have a role, and I assigned it to a user

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To access the Azure AD API, you have to grant your app with right permissions. On your API Application go to API Permissions page, select Grant admin consent.
[image]

Comment: Please see the update. Still no roles are listed for the user.

Comment: I don't know maybe you need 'Application permission' depends on the way that your app interact with Azure! try `Application permission`

Comment: Does not work either.

Comment: Logout and login again !

Comment: Not working. The `userName = user.Identity.Name` part worked fine before and now.But the role count is `0`.

Comment: Please see this: https://damienbod.com/2021/02/01/implement-app-roles-authorization-with-azure-ad-and-asp-net-core/

Comment: Did you see this tutorial ?